# How to remove SSL certificate check/error with puppeteer in headless mode.?

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, google-chrome-headless, cookieyes, cookieserve

Tried below code but getting an error.

> Error: net::ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH at
> https://www.xxxxxxsolutions.com/

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");
(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
    acceptInsecureCerts: true,
    args: [
      "--proxy-bypass-list=*",
      "--disable-gpu",
      "--disable-dev-shm-usage",
      "--disable-setuid-sandbox",
      "--no-first-run",
      "--no-sandbox",
      "--no-zygote",
      "--single-process",
      "--ignore-certificate-errors",
      "--ignore-certificate-errors-spki-list",
      "--enable-features=NetworkService",
    ],
  });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  try {
    await page.goto("https://www.xxxxxxxsolutions.com/", {
      waitUntil: "networkidle2",
      timeout: 59000,
    });
    const cookies = await page._client.send("Network.getAllCookies");
    JSON.stringify(cookies, null, 4);
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }

  await browser.close();
})();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@mujuonly, this is version related issue. Please try the same code above 1.16.0 or latest version 2.0. It's working fine.